# Regex filenames, Python

Tags: python, regex, glob

I'm trying to get all files with excel format extensions, therefore I thought this would select any file that has xls in the filename. It would pick up on xls, xlsx, xlsm etc.

the path is a variable defined as the folder I'm extracting these files from and all_files is storing these files. shouldn't the /* define any file that has .xls in it? `/*.xlsx` or `/*.xlsm` works fine.

```
all_files=glob.glob(path + "/*.xls/*")
```

Comment: glob.glob("/*.xls") selects xls files only

Comment: What `/` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get all files that have `.xls` in them, and you're trying the glob pattern:

```
/*.xls/*
```

This will find directories (note the trailing `/`) that end in `.xls`, not files.

You need:

```
glob.glob(path + "/*.xls*")
```

but that would not be precise, as this would match any file having just the string `.xls` in them e.g. `foo.xlsbar`.

The problem is that the standard shell globbing (even leveraging `[]`, `?` would not do here) is not so flexible as Regex as needed here, you can wrap the glob in some Regex check afterwards:

```
import glob
import re
req = re.compile(r'\.xls[xm]?$')
all_files = list(filter(lambda x: req.search(x), glob.iglob(path + '/*.xls*')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "/" in your expression. To add the wildcard to the end of ".xls" you need:

```
all_files=glob.glob(path + "/*.xls*")
```